# Video Streaming using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, video-streaming

I'm starting a new project to play the video on my LAN, actually if I enter an IP on my browser I got a m3u file with the following info:

http://192.168.1.101:31344

So, if I open that file Im able to see the video using VLC Media Player. However in the school, I proposed to implement my own video player. I know there are some options, like DirectX, Silverlight, etc.. so I'm looking for recommendations on which technology use so any advice is welcome.

I don't have any restriction, the only one is to use C# on VS 2010 Professional.

Thanks,
m0dest0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is overly-broad in scope. I would suggest that this is either (a) very trivial (embed media-player), or (b) incredibly complex, doubtless requiring native interop... in this case the project becomes somewhat more than C#. Neither approach sounds appropriate for a school project, and the latter would require skills of quite high calibre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've used Silverlight with an embedded [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) and just set the source to the address of the video file.  It was simple to use.  I wouldn't call it "writing your own video player", but it should do.

There's plenty of examples in the link I gave you.